# Debian bridged network between virtual machines

Tags: debian, bridge, lxc

I installed two linux containers (lxc) in a debian squeeze server so the environment is as follows:

Physical server: 192.168.2.200
Linux container 1: 192.168.2.201
Linux container 2: 192.168.2.202
Bridge between physical server and containers: 10.0.0.100

I created the bridge between the physical server and the lxc containers using parprouted, uml-utilities and bcrelay packages.

I have a script in /etc/network/if-up.d that executes via post-up command. The following is the content of that script:

```
brctl addbr br0
tunctl -t tap0
brctl addif br0 tap0
ip addr add 10.0.0.100/32 dev br0
ip link set br0 up
parprouted eth0 br0
bcrelay -d -i br0 -o eth0
# Linux container 1
route add -host 192.168.2.201 dev br0
# Linux container 2
route add -host 192.168.2.202 dev br0
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

So far so good. Linux containers can access internet without any problems and the physical server can ping and ssh to both Linux containers. Linux containers can ping and ssh the physical server.

The problem is that I cannot access Linux container 1 from Linux container 2 and viceversa. They cannot ping each other and they cannot ssh each other either.

I'm very close to achieve this.

What else do I need to make the Linux containers talk to each other?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is a problem with the default Squeeze kernel (2.6.32).

Using exactly the same setup with a backported kernel (3.2) will allow you to ping/connect host directly.